# Sweep Line Algorithm: AVL tree for neighboring line segments

Tags: algorithm, geometry, computational-geometry, intersection

I am currently trying to implement the sweep line algorithm for line segments intersection for Unity in C#.
I am using the book "Computational Geometry, Algorithms and Applications, 3rd Edition" by "Mark de Berg· Otfried Cheong. Marc van Kreveld· Mark Overmar."
PDF: https://people.inf.elte.hu/fekete/algoritmusok_msc/terinfo_geom/konyvek/Computational%20Geometry%20-%20Algorithms%20and%20Applications,%203rd%20Ed.pdf

At the moment I'm trying to implement the 2 datastructures: An AVL Tree for the Events and an AVL Tree for the line segments ordered by the x axis.

I successfully implemented the events structure, but I am struggling with the line segments structure: On page 25 of the book (P. 35 in the pdf) it explains how we store the line segments only in the leaves of the tree, but how would one implement such a tree? Since the other nodes in the trees are still "segments" but only serve as values to guide the search, it means that all segments will be in the tree twice. But doesn't an AVL tree only have each value once? and if not, how would you order them.
Beyond that, I don't fully understand the sentence "Suppose we search in T for the
segment immediately to the left of some point p that lies on the sweep line. At
each internal node ν we test whether p lies left or right of the segment stored
at ν. Depending on the outcome we descend to the left or right subtree of ν,
eventually ending up in a leaf. Either this leaf, or the leaf immediately to the left
of it, stores the segment we are searching for." That sentence is on page 25 as well.

Firstof, when would we descend to the left and when to the right? And why could also the leaf immediately to the left be the leaf we are looking for?

Hopefully I didnt write too much text. Thanks!

Comment: It's sort of like how B+ trees are different from B trees.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! If I used a regular AVL tree and stored the segments in every node, would the algorithm significantly change? In the book it says that storing the segments only in the leave nodes simplifies the algorithm but it doesn't state why that is. I don't see why it would simplify the algorithm at all.

Comment: I don't remember if I've implemented this algorithm specifically. There's a similar design choice in implementing dynamic trees, though, and the choice seemed like a wash to me. The nice part about using the interior nodes is that the space usage is halved.